# How to get started with using Dapper.Mapper?

Tags: c#, dapper

I am using [Dapper.Mapper](https://github.com/dotarj/Dapper.Mapper) for mapping Sql queries to my application classes directly. I believed Dapper.Mapper is just a syntactical sugar-coating over [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper), the original ORM. But, I am still not able to head-start with it due to very less demos and examples. However I have tried this as per their git page:

```
var sql="Select * from Students where Grades>90"'
var conn=new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[0].ConnectionString);
var studentRecord=conn.Query<Students, TopStudents>(sql);
```

And my POCO models are:

```
//Db table    
public class Students
{
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public float Grades{get;set;}
}

public class TopStudents
{
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public string Grades{get;set;}
    //...Few more properties
}
```

But I am getting following exception, `No Writable Property for TopStudents found in types Students`

Am I missing something? Please share any quick demo or tutorial. There is not even a proper documentation where I can find the exception's cause and resolve it myself. How to get started with Dapper.Mapper?

Comment: Your query only returns `Students`, so why have you got `TopStudents` as a query argument? You're specifying what objects dapper should use to deserialize the row.

Comment: Okay let me understand it, the first argument (`Student` object) is the source whose output I want to **map** to second argument (`TopStudents` object). Isn't this understanding correct? If not, kindly correct me. Thanks

Comment: So it means, that second parameter inside `<` and `>` donot map the first one? If I would have 4 joins, there will be 4 objects as parameters in there?

Comment: Using this technique, yes.  In reality, you'd write the query toreturn only the fields you wanted and dapper would map this to a custom model that you would create yourself. Dapper does this by default, no need for an extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the docs [here](https://github.com/dotarj/Dapper.Mapper), the example query uses select * and uses an inner join, so it's returning Employee AND Department objects.  If it was only returning Employee objects, then the code would look like this:

```
var sql = @"select * from Employee";

var employee = connection.Query<Employee, Department>(sql);
```

Applying this to your code:

```
var sql="Select * from Students where Grades>90"'
var conn=new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[0].ConnectionString);
var studentRecord=conn.Query<Students>(sql);
```

If you want to return `Students` and `TopStudents`, then you would change it to something like:

```
var sql="Select * from Students s
INNER JOIN TopStudents ts where s.Id = ts.Id AND s.Grades>90"'
var conn=new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[0].ConnectionString);
var studentRecord=conn.Query<Students, TopStudents>(sql);
```

Comment: Ohkay now I got it..I was thinking that query's output is mapped to `Students` whose serialized property then maps to `TopStudent` . Thanks for clarifying :)

Comment: Just one last query: What will be typeof `studentRecord` variable in your answer: `Students` or `TopStudents`?

Comment: `studentRecord` will contain both `Students` and `TopStudents`.  I'm not really sure why you would use this technique over simply mapping to a custom model.